# How to compute the sum of a power series in a more robust way?

Tags: numerical-analysis

In order to compute the sum of a power series, we can use for loop, while loop or the analytic formula. I am wondering what is difference between those algorithms and how to improve the robustness of this question?

Comment: Hi @Doudou, and welcome to Scicomp!  Could you clarify what you mean by improving the robustness?

Comment: @Doudou: maybe also what you mean by "the analytic formula"? Do you mean a closed form solution of an infinite series?

Comment: One general comment: If you have a bunch of floating point numbers that you need to add together, add them in order from smallest to largest. Occasionally I've seen numeric analysts use a priority queue to ensure that the two smallest numbers are always added in any step. This minimises roundoff error. (Proof left as an exercise.)